# (Tic-Tac-Toe) Apps Keeps Stopping

Tags: java, android

when i click the Replay button it causes error, App keep stopping.

i try to make null to ImageView and probably it is the problem :(

```
 Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
                    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            GridLayout grd=(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
                            for(int i=0; i<grd.getChildCount(); i++)
                            {
                                ImageView counter=(ImageView) grd.getChildAt(i);
                                counter.setImageDrawable(null);
                                gameState[i]=2;

                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In future, please share the error (can be located under the **Logcat** window). Since you didn't share the error, I had to download the project and replicate the error on my instance. 
The error which you are facing is the following

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout
    at com.example.tic_toc.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
```

So this is basically invalid **cast** type. Your XML file is using **android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout** element. Whereas, in your code, you are trying to assign it against **android.widget.GridLayout**. 

This can be solved by replacing

```
import android.widget.GridLayout;
```

with

```
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
```

in your MainActivity.java

Comment: thnx a lot my friend and also I'm so sorry for skipping the Logcat,i'm the new guy here.